# Reverse Collections

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I'm trying to reverse my Collections, which is comprised of two ArrayList (that have the same objects). It reverses the two ArrayList separately, like this:

Sadie

Carl

Sadie

Carl

But I want them to be sorted together like:

Sadie

Sadie

Carl

Carl

I tried adding Collections.reverse twice (like I did for remove), but that did not work. Is it possible or should I just give up? Here's my current code:

```
    List<People> peopleList = new ArrayList<People>();
    Student student1 = new Student("Diana", "Carter", new Date("09/15/1992"), 111222333);
    peopleList.add(student1);
    Faculty faculty1 = new Faculty("Clark", "Kent", new Date("05/22/1990"), 199242003,
            323232);
    peopleList.add(faculty1);
    Staff staff1 = new Staff("Bruce", "Wayne", new Date("01/01/1993"),  161257235,
            100000);
    peopleList.add(staff1);
    Collections.addAll(peopleList);

    ArrayList<People> peopleListClone = new ArrayList<People>();
    peopleListClone.addAll(peopleList);
    peopleListClone.addAll(peopleList);

    Collections.addAll(peopleListClone);
    DisplayPeople(peopleListClone, "////////////////// People list clone     initialized.");

    peopleListClone.remove(student1);
    peopleListClone.remove(student1);
    DisplayPeople(peopleListClone, "////////////////// People list after student elements removed.");

    Collections.reverse(peopleListClone);
    Collections.reverse(peopleListClone);
    DisplayPeople(peopleListClone, "////////////////// People list clone sorted in reverse.");
```

Comment: you have 2 arraylists with the same objects?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to teach myself to add the same ArrayList twice and then reverse it. Did I do it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
List<People> peopleListClone = peopleList.stream()
    .flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s, s))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<People> peopleListClone = new ArrayList<People>();
peopleListClone.addAll(peopleList);
peopleListClone.addAll(peopleList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't quite get what you were trying to achieve with the code you had written out. Let me know if this helps you understand cloning and reversing `ArrayLists` in any way.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("apple");
list.add("ball");
list.add("cat");
list.add("dog");            // [apple, ball, cat, dog]  
Collections.reverse(list);
System.out.println(list);   // [dog, cat, ball, apple]

List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
list2.addAll(list);         // MAKING A HARD COPY

Collections.reverse(list2); // REVERSING THE HARD COPY
System.out.println(list2);  // [apple, ball, cat, dog]  REVERSED HARD COPY
System.out.println(list);   // [dog, cat, ball, apple] STILL THE SAME ORIGINAL
```

Comment: Thank you. That really helped. I'm using Deitel's Java How to Program and it really doesn't delve much into cloning.

Comment: @BoyGeorge It would be nice, if you could accept/upvote an answer if your issue is resolved. From [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), "Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved."